# Amazon SageMaker recommendation capabilities

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

There is this example

https://medium.com/@julsimon/building-a-movie-recommender-with-factorization-machines-on-amazon-sagemaker-cedbfc8c93d8

where the model returns the 'score' of the movie you asked for so you can recommend it or not.
Can it be made to return the top 10 movies for a specific user?

It can be done with Amazon EMR 
(like this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-a-recommendation-engine-with-spark-ml-on-amazon-emr-using-zeppelin/ ) 
but that solution does not offer the ease of a REST endpoint for live recommendations(I'm baffled with JobServer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of this post :)

FM will "simply" fill the missing values in the recommendation matrix. What you could do is batch-predict all movies for all users, sort the results by descending score and store the top 10 results for each user in a cache, why not. That would make it easy to retrieve results in real-time from any kind of app.  I suppose you would also retrain periodically to account for new user recos.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however i thought the request would be too big if i had to ask for 2 million users and 400k products :S (I will accept this answer as correct as there seems to be no other out of the box solution)